# path to array value deep multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array

I have an array where I need the path (keys) to a given value. I've written a function for it but I can't get it working, the array can have an infinite depth to be controlled in another function, I haven't decided on a limit yet but the depth is variable, it actually works up to a point but the depth may be 30-40-50 deep so I need it to work that way, this function is really just for value identification, the numbers are templates, the tags are tags in the templates, each tag has a single template associated with it, all template names are unique and tags names aren't because they are only associated with a single template, id values are separated by a dash (illegal in template and tag ids), where template ids are only numeric and tag ids are wrapped with squigglies and a dollar sign like so {$TAG}, don't have to worry about duplicate values because infinite loops are forbidden (template can't link to itself or a template that links to itself) plus ids are given only to templates where template names are unique. The id of the template named 4 in the given array would be 0-{$CONTENT}-2-{$PARAGRAPH}-4, where I lose it is my function won't go beyond this depth, thanks for the help

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      '{$TITLE}' => null
      '{$NAME}' => null
      '{$FRIENDS}' => 
          array (size=1)
            1 => 
              array (size=2)
                '{$friend}' => null
                '{$friends[$i]}' => null
      '{$CONTENT}' => 
        array (size=1)
          2 => 
             '{$HEADING}' => 
               array (size=1)
                 3 => 
                   array (size=0)
                     empty
             '{$PARAGRAPH}' => 
               array (size=1)
                 4 => 
                   array (size=1)
                     '{$AnotherParagraph}' => null
```

here is my function, I've added the depth variable just for testing purposes, $this->family is the array given above, calling the function: $id = $this->get_id(4);

```
public function get_id($member, $family=null, $id=null, $depth=0) {
    if (empty($this->family)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (is_null($family)) {
        $family = $this->family;
    }

    foreach ($family as $parent => $tag_child) {
        if ($member === $parent) {
            return $member;
        }

        foreach ($tag_child as $tag => $child) {
            if (is_null($child) || empty($child)) {
                continue;
            }

            $childkey = key($child);

            if ($member === $childkey) {
                $id .= '-'.$parent.'-'.$tag.'-'.$member;
                $id = ltrim($id, '-');
                return $id;
            }

            $family = $child;

            if (!is_null($id) && !empty($id)) {
                $id_array = explode('-', $id);
                foreach ($id_array as $id_value) {
                    if ($id_value !== $childkey) {
                        $new_id_array[] = $id_value;
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $id = implode('-', $new_id_array);
            }

            if ($parent === 0) {
                $id = $parent.'-'.$tag.'-'.$childkey;
            }else{
                $id .= '-'.$tag.'-'.$childkey;
            }

            $id = ltrim($id, '-');

            $depth++;

            $id = $this->get_id($member, $family, $id, $depth);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning the array keys? The way you have it setup is bad because by default the keys are assigned numeric values, you have something that should be sitting at index 0 as 4. As soon as you get another array at the top level your script will break.

Comment: because the nature of templates it runs on a base template concept, when the base template is compiled there will be in the end only one html file that will be sent to the browser, the purpose of the class is to keep a base template and record of all the children, the class is PTE_Family and the function I'm using to set the array is in the next comment

Comment: ` public function set_value($id, $member) {
  $var =& $this->family;
  $id = explode('-', $id);
  array_pop($id);
  foreach ($id as $key) {
   if (array_key_exists($key, $var)) {
    $var =& $var[$key];
   }else{
    return false;
   }
  }
  $var = $member;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function. Here's one I wrote for this EXACT purpose.

```
public function recurseArray($array, $builtKey = "") {
    $values = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!empty($builtKey)) {
                $values = array_merge($values, recurseArray($value, $builtKey.".".$key));
            } else {
                $values = array_merge($values, recurseArray($value, $key));
            }
        } else {
            if (!empty($builtKey)) {
                $values[$builtKey.".".$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $values[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

This results in a flat array that transforms this:

```
array(
    "key" => array(
        "of" => array(
            "many" => array(
                "depths" => "value"
            )
        )
    ),
    "key2" => "value"
);
```

Into this:

```
array(
    "key.of.many.depths" => "value",
    "key2" => "value"
);
```

Comment: Working on it? Do you need something else, or are you working on implementing the function I provided, or are you working on your own?

Comment: BTW, if you put this function inside of a class (like I originally had it) don't forget to change the two calls INSIDE the function from recurseArray() to $this->recurseArray()

Comment: trying to make it return string: 0-{$CONTENT}-2-{$PARAGRAPH}-4

Comment: This will return whatever the format of the array is. If you want it to concat with "-" instead of "." you can change it in two lines (line 6 and 12 of the function I provided).

Comment: it appears that this identifies the deepest level of the array, which don't get me wrong is very useful and I'll be adding it (if its cool with you) to my library, but I need to identify a given value at any depth, I'm gonna keep trying to work it though, it's a very interesting function you have here, please correct me if I'm wrong about it, I need some way to build a id, and then unbuild it to a point if that branch doesn't contain the value

Comment: It works with arrays of arbitrary depth. This doesn't help you that much if you don't know where your key path might be. For instance if you wanted to find a 0-stuff-2-otherstuff where the 0 started at ANY depth... well you could combine this function with a strpos() on the key, but mostly I think you're probably SOL, because that's just a poor way to use array in general.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your needs?

Comment: i probably am sol, I can't think a better way to store the deep relationships between templates than an array, I could store the child in the parent template object but how is that better than an array, the template objects are stored in a simple 1 dimensional array, this is just keeping the relationships between the objects

Comment: on another note I've been sol before and I'll probably be sol again, but your function is definitely taking me in new directions, I may end up building the id as an array and converting it to a string, or something I don't know, I don't even have a computer, I've been hashing this out on paper for weeks and my time here is almost up, I'll keep you posted here how it all works out anyway

Comment: Oh wow! Well good luck Sir, I hope you find a solution that works for you.

Comment: if you're still out there I'd like to send you my stuff on this question but not sure if you want to or we even could exchange information on this site without it being public so if your interested or have an idea how to do this add another comment here please, oh and happy thanksgiving

Comment: i think i got it, i was having several problems, the last of which was comparing numbers to strings that contain numbers so now I'm using == instead of ===, I'd like to show you: JRL, the completed code with related classes but I don't really want to post it here unless there is more interest in the post from the public, comment here if you would like me to send you the entire package as it's not online or anywhere yet